# How do inject a dependency that has other auto wired dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I did my home work on this, however i always end up in single layer of dependency solutions,
what I'm trying to do, is use annotation based Spring DI, to inject my dependencies.

```
public interface SpringJpaStudentRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentEntity, UUID> {
}


class DataSourceImpl extends StudentDataSource {
    final SpringJpaStudentRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public DataSourceImpl(SpringJpaStudentRepository repository) {
        ...
    }
}

class RepositoryImpl implements StudentRepository {
    final DataSourceImpl dataSource;

    @Autowired
    RepositoryImpl(DataSourceImpl dataSource) {
        ...
    }
}
```

From what i know, i must make a bean configuration class to create DatasourceImpl to inject to RepositoryImpl, however i couldn't just pull it off with a new because DatasourceImpl also needs SpringJpaStudentRepository as an injected dependency, how do i deal with this scenario?

Comment: Whether you have 1, 2, 3 or more layers doesn't change anything to the way you inject dependencies. As long as those dependencies are Spring beans, you can autowire them. What's the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: When i create a bean provider for DataSourceImpl, i should be using new DataSourceImpl(SpringJpaStudentRepository) which i couldn't i have no access to SpringJpaStudentRepository to instance. the problem is, how do you instantiate a dependency object that has another dependency which you may, or may not have access to.

Comment: Assuming that by "bean provider", you mean a method annotated with `@Bean` in a class annotated with `@configuration`, you add the SpringJpaStudentRepository as an argument to the method. If you mean something else, then post the code. But why do you use such a method instead of annotating DataSourceImpl with `@Component` or `@Service`?